# Custom width and auto height to dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

How do i set a custom width to the dropdown list items in bootstrap 3.0.

I have a dropdown list, but the width of the items is usually the same size for all, and that size is determined by the longest item width.

Is it possible to customize the width and if the item words ar too long to fit, then wrap them?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change inline things but you can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ2Lg/638/)

html

```
<ul>
    <li><span>&nbsp;</span> The lazy dog.</li>
    <li><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> The lazy cat.</li>
    <li><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> The active goldfish.</li>
    </ul>
```

css

```
 ul 
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    ul li span { 
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
    }
```